# is there a syntax to search for only training entries that are "not learned"?

Tags: bixby

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/training.intro-training#searching-through-training-examples

I want to find only entries that are not learned status, but do not see a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bixby currently does not support this functionality.

I would recommend that you raise a [Feature Request](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000183273-Feature-Requests) in our community. This forum is open to other Bixby developers who can upvote it, leading to more visibility within the community and with the Product Management team.